# Issue with adding element to <body> after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are adding a background image to the 'body' tag. The image is dynamic so has to be loaded last to allow variables to be passed to it.

The issue is, we are trying to improve our PageSpeed and when adding the background image, the PageSpeed report is marking a whole lot of script as render-blocking. Even one we have in our footer.

As far as I know this shouldn't be render-blocking because the content can load fine without it - and it does - but when the background image is called, it becomes render-blocking.

Has anyone done anything like this before? Any workarounds?

I've also spent copious amounts of time trying to get the script to load after the page has finished loading, and I have made it load after the page, but the render-blocking content is still marked in the report.

I can't seem to make any sense of it all. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
bhtech

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/header.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/footer.js"></script>
<script src="/loadbodyimage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the /loadbodyimage.js file isn't included, only the /header.js file is render-blocking - which makes perfect sense.

But when I include the /loadbodyimage.js (which adds a background image to the body tag) the /footer.js file also becomes render-blocking.

That's a very dumbed down version of what's going on - but kind of illustrates what I'm experiencing.

**UPDATE**

I've added the following code to the bottom of my page which writes to the body tag and adds a background image. It's simple jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').css('background', 'url(/images/bgImage.jpg)');
});
```

This makes scripts on the page (even after it) get marked as render-blocking. If I comment this line out, the scripts are no longer render-blocking. I hope that helps to explain my issue.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code... Oh wait, you forgot to include any code in your question. Help us to help you by including a cut-down version of your problem code - just the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving a script called [head.js](http://headjs.com/) a try. It loads JS asynchronously and in parallel. I've had excellent results with it when trying to improve PageSpeed scores and initial page load times.

You can download head.js [here](http://headjs.com/).

Usage:

```
<head>
 <script src="/head.load.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  head.js("/header.js");
  head.js("/footer.js");
  head.js("/loadbodyimage.js");
 </script>
</head>
```